# Model comparison with AIC based on different sample size

Tags: model-selection, aic, model-comparison

Let's assume I have two models M1 and M2:

```
M1:  y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
M2:  y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
```

Since variable x4 has some missing values the sample size of M2 is lower than sample size of M1: n2 < n1.
Is it still admissible to use AIC to compare models based on different sample sizes?

Comment: In general, we should use identical test-set to compare models. It is not sufficient to have same test set sample size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the information criteria are based on likelihood function, which in its turn depends on sample size. The larger sample size is, the smaller likelihood becomes and as a result the greater IC becomes. So, you should expect that with the increase of sample size, IC will increase as well (whatever criteria you use). This means that you cannot compare different models fitted on different sample sizes using any information criteria.

BIC has a different penalty than AIC and AICc ($\log(n)k$ instead of $2k$) but it is still based on likelihood function and suffers from the same problem.

As for AICc, this is an unbiased estimate of AIC that can be used on small samples. Once again, it does not allow to compare models on different sample sizes for the same reason as described above. It is just more reliable than AIC when you work with small samples and large number of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for this post. Would BIC truly solve the problem of comparing models with different sample size then? Still not clear to me, do you have a book/paper on someone using it? Thanks,
Norber

Answer (score 1):

A commonly used formula for AIC is AIC = n*ln(RSS/n)+2k, where n is sample size, RSS is regression sum of squares, and k is number parameters (Legendre and Legendre, Numerical Ecology 2012). It can be adjusted for small sample size, as above mentioned. RSS is calculated as RSS = sum[(y_est-y_mean)^2]. Independence of observations, normality of residuals, and homogeneity of residual variances are assumed. The Legendre text at one point states,..."AIC is used to compare models of the same response data,..." and many online sources say y data needs to be the same as well. I didn't see anyone explain why. However, If one were to take additional samples, the above formula implies AIC could go up or down simply by adding those additional samples (as Giordano pointed out). Intuitively, that does not seem appropriate, and so it also seems inappropriate to compare models with different sample size.

Comment: Regression sum of squares is divided by n but than after logarithmizing multiplied by n. It makes Likelihood again dependent of n.

Comment: The same (Legendre and Legendre) reference I mentioned states later in the text, "Since AIC is used to compare models of the same response data..." and I looked around online and many people do mention that the y data needs to be the same, so I am assuming they have a valid reason for stating so. Looking further, that n you mention does change AIC simply due to sample size, and so intuitively, it does seem then that sample size at least should be the same. You've convinced me and answered your own question. I was wrong. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

There is [AICc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#AICc), which is AIC with a correction for sample size:

```
AICc = AIC + 2k(k + 1)/(n - k - 1)
```

where ''n'' denotes the sample size and ''k'' denotes the number of parameters.

I think AICc can be used to compare models based on different sample sizes.

Comment: (-1) No, AICc just adds an adjustment to the bias-correction term.

Answer (score -3):

My rule of thumb is to use BIC instead of AIC when sample sizes are different. AIC is still admissible, the log likelihood input indirectly accounts for different sample sizes.

Comment: (-1) That's not true! The likelihood is a joint probability density, so even for the same model it can vary enormously between different sample sizes. Or am I completely misunderstanding what you're saying?