# Convince me that AIC can't be used to compare models with different sample sizes

Tags: model-selection, sample-size, aic

Conventional statistical wisdom says we cannot compare AIC (or other information criteria predictive sample statistics) when the sample sizes for the compared models are different (See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94718/model-comparison-with-aic-based-on-different-sample-size) for example).

I need to be convinced that is true.

Below is the AIC formula for a linear model.

$AIC = 2k + n Log(RSS/n)$

It seems to me that the sample size is accounted for in the formula. Where are am I misunderstanding?

Comment: At a high level, AIC is a measure of model fit, so if you compare the AICs of two models that are fit on different datasets (whether the datasets are the same size or not), how much is the difference in AIC due to different models and how much is due to different data? A model that fits one dataset well could fit another poorly.

Comment: Hi: The AIC can be written as a function of the log likelhood and the log likelihood changes ( increases actually ) the more observations one has because it's a sum. So, you need to have the same number of samples in order for the comparison to be fair.

Comment: Holding $k$ and RSS constant, what happens to this formula as $n$ grows?  *QED.*

Comment: @mlofton log(x) < 0 if x<1.

Comment: @Richard $\text{RSS}/n$ ought to be converging to the true underlying value.

Comment: @Richard Thank you for pointing that out: I mean to hold $\text{RSS}/n$ constant, of course.

Comment: @a_statistician: my mistake. I should have said the likelihood. not log likelihood thanks for correction..

Comment: @mlofton sometimes the likelihood decreases when you add more obs.

Comment: @a_statistician: Can you provide an example ? Each observation has a likelihood density and you're adding them so I don't see that. Thanks.

Comment: @mlofton For log-likelihood, you're adding them($\sum_{i=1}^n$), for likelihood, you're timing them ($\prod_{i=1}^n$)

Comment: true. and you're saying that some of the log likelihood terms can be negative and some of them positive which makes it not necessarily increasing. interesting. I learned something. thanks.

Comment: @mlofton Log in monotonic increase function, so log-likelihood and likelihood increase or decrease together. For the discrete distribution, likelihood will decrease along more items are added, because the probability <= 1. For continue distribution, increase or decrease depends on the density. For example, if distribution is unif(0,0.5), likelihood will increase; for unif(0,2), it will decrease.