# BIC model comparison

Tags: bayesian, model-comparison, bic

My go/nogo task was recorded in 4 blocks, each with a new set of cue images, with the learning and therefore the Q-values being reset at the beginning of each block.
I have fitted different versions of a Q-learning-based Rescorla-Wagner model on my behavior dataset, once on the whole dataset irrespective of the blocks, and once separately on each block.
This way, I'm using the exact same models, but once I am including block as a degree of freedom, and once not.
I have a set of BIC scores for the models for when I fit completely, and 4 sets of BIC scores for when I fit on each block.
To decide which approach is better, to fit completely or to fit block-wise, should I simply use BIC scores?
How should I integrate the BIC scores of the block-wise fit into one, so that I can compare it with the one from the full fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIC and BIC depend on likelihood functions which also depend on sample size. If splitting by block means each model has a different sample size (and sample frame), there is no meaningful way to compare the AIC and BIC scores I believe.

Likewise, you cannot compare the overall model AIC/BIC to the individual block models if the block models only contain a subset of the data. If, however, it is the same data but just fewer parameters in the model, you can use the AIC/BIC to pick the better model.

Hope that helps!

Here is a previous post about comparing AIC and BIC scores on models with different sample sizes:

[https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94718/model-comparison-with-aic-based-on-different-sample-size#:~:text=My%20rule%20of%20thumb%20is,accounts%20for%20different%20sample%20sizes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94718/model-comparison-with-aic-based-on-different-sample-size#:%7E:text=My%20rule%20of%20thumb%20is,accounts%20for%20different%20sample%20sizes).

Comment: Thank you @Rob_research, this helps a lot! Then do you have a suggestion of how to decide, to fit on the whole data or block-wise?

Comment: You could always do both and report both sets of results? I think it comes down to whether there is a theoretical justification for looking at the results block by block. If you believe the blocks will differ substantially, then splitting by block is probably useful! Otherwise, fitting overall is fine and including a control variable for the block will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rob_research!